# str.replace is not a function in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am returning objects from the backend to fill them in the select component but for some reason when I receive the data I get the error str.replace is not a function and when I do not receive data (that is, there are no matches) the select field shows the [Object Promise] text and I can't change or delete it.

```
const [selectedMedico, setSelectedMedico] = useState(null);
const [medicoOptions, setMedicoOptions] = useState([]);

const handleSearch = async (inputValue) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/buscar-usuarios?search=${inputValue}`);
      const medicoData = response.data; // Array de objetos con la información del médico
      const options = medicoData ? medicoData.map((medico) => ({ value: medico._id, label: `${medico.nombre} ${medico.apellido}` })) : [];
      setMedicoOptions(options);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al realizar la búsqueda:', error);
      // Puedes imprimir más información sobre el error, por ejemplo:
      console.error('Error response:', error.response);
      console.error('Error message:', error.message);
      // ...
    }
  };



<div className="row mb-3">
                    <label htmlFor="inputMedico" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Médico</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                      <Controller
                        name="medico"
                        control={control}
                        rules={{ required: "El nombre del médico es obligatorio" }}
                        render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
                          <Select
                            {...field}
                            id="inputMedico"
                            name="medico"
                            placeholder="Seleccione un médico"
                            value={selectedMedico}
                            options={medicoOptions}
                            onChange={(value) => {
                              field.onChange(value);
                              setSelectedMedico(value instanceof Promise ? null : value);
                            }}
                            onInputChange={(inputValue) => handleSearch(inputValue)}
                          />
                        )}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: not clear which library you are using for Select and also does your endpoint(buscar-usuarios) return an array of objects with type `{_id: string, nombre: string, apellido: string}`